# Property - Auto property synthesis is synthesizing property not explicitly synthesized

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, synthesis

I turned on -Weverything just to see what would be flagged.  I received this warning on nearly every property.

"Auto property synthesis is synthesizing property not explicitly synthesized"

I read other posts and understand I can just manually add @synthesis blahBlah; for every property but that seems to defeat the whole point of auto synthesis.  Why isn't it smarter about when to issue the warning instead of all of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "smarter"? When shouldn't it issue the warning?

You should only turn this warning on if you don't want to use auto synthesis - it will then warn you in case you forgot to synthesize a property.

If you are using auto synthesis then you should suppress the warning. You have unsuppressed it, so it gives you the warning.

Comment: Fair enough, I just figured since it was part of the compiler, why have a warning for something it is supposed to be doing.  I marked this is the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: A person or organisation may decide that they don't want to use auto synthesis for some reason. This warning gives them the option of being warned if they forget to synthesise something.